# Windows Active Directory Domain setup remotely through univention using samba4

Tags: dns, active-directory

I have a slight problem bit of the back story. recently ive been trying to test out univention which is a linux distribution with the goal of being able to replace Microsoft active directory.

I tested it locally and all went reasonably well after a few minor issues i then decided to test it remotely as the company wants to allow remote users to access this so i used myhyve.com to host it and its now been setup successfully and works reasonably well.

however
my main problem is DNS based as when trying to connect to the domain the only way windows will recognize it is by editing the network adapter and setting ip v4 dns server address to the ip address of the server hosting the univention active directory replacement. although this does allow every thing to work its not ideal and dns look up on the internet are considerably longer. i was wondering if any one had any ideas or have done something similar and encountered this problems before and know a work around. i want to avoid setting up a vpn if possible.

after initially registering the computer on the domain i am able to remove the dns server address and just use a couple of amendments to the HOST file to keep it running but this still leads to having issues connecting to the domain controller sometimes and is not ideal. any ideas and suggestions would be greatly received.

.Michael

Comment: Few more details i have full control over the machines but not over the network there on currently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the HOST entries, the most likely issue is, that there are several service records a computer in the domain needs. I'm not sure, whether these can be provided via the HOST file or not but you'll definitely have authentication issues if they are missing. To see the records your domain is using issue the following commands on the UCS system.

`/usr/share/univention-samba4/scripts/check_essential_samba4_dns_records.sh`

For the slow resolution of the DNS records there are several points where you could start looking. My first test would be whether or not you are using a forwarder for the web DNS requests and whether or not the forwarder is having a decent speed. To check if you are using one, type

`ucr search dns/forwarder`

If you get a valid IP for either of the UCR Variables, dns/forwarder1, dns/forwarder2 or dns/forwarder3, you are forwarding your DNS requests to a different Server. If all of them are empty or not valid IPs then your server is doing the resolution itself.

Not using a forwarder is often slow, as the DNS servers caching is optimized for the AD operations, like the round robin load balancing. Likewise a number of ISPs require you to use a forwarder to minimize the DNS traffic. You can simply define a forwarder using ucr, I use Google on IPv4 for the example

`ucr set dns/forwarder1='8.8.8.8'`

The other scenario might be a slow forwarder. To check it try to query the forwarder directly using the following command

`dig univention.com @(ucr get dns/forwarder1)`

If it takes long, then there is nothing the UCS server can do, you'll simply have to choose a different forwarder from the ucr command above.

If neither of the above helps, the next step would be to check whether there are error messages for the `named` daemon in the syslog file. Normally these come when you are trying to manually remove software or if the firewall configuration got changed.

Kevin

Sponsored post, as I work for Univention North America, Inc.